# Hostname troubles

Tags: dns, hostname

I am trying to change the hostname on a Linux RHEL6.5 box and have changed it in `/etc/hosts` and in `/etc/sysconfig/network`, as I have read..

The command `hostname`'now returns the new hostname, but `hostname -A` returns the old one, and I still cannot connect to the machine using the new one.

I have restarted the network service and everyting, restarted the box, but still no luck.

Can someone please explain why this isn't working for me?

Comment: `I still cannot connect to the machine using the new one`. Are you doing this from the same machine or from a different machine? Cause if it is from the different machine then it must ask DNS to resolve a name and it seems you have not added the new name to DNS.

Comment: Have you tried `hostname $new_hostname`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following from the system you are trying to connect from:

```
nslookup <new hostname>
```

I suspect you'll get:

```
** server can't find thisdoesntexist.com: NXDOMAIN
```

In which case, you need to update your DNS server with the new hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to put it in /etc/hostname and a reboot is advisable.